# Fluent NHibernate HasMany where source is a comma separated string of Ids

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Im' trying to wrap my head around fluent nHibernate while trying to do this kind of mapping:

```
public class ClassA : Entity
{
   public virtual string SomeField { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : Entity
{
   public virtual string ClassAIds { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<ClassA> ClassAList { get; set; }
}
```

Where Entity basically ensures that both classes have Id field as their primary database key.

Database would look like:

```
 table ClassA:
   int Id,
   varchar(25) SomeField


 table ClassB:
   int Id,
   varchar(50) ClassAIds
```

I'm trying to write some map so that ClassB object would be populated with ClassA entities into ClassAList. Is it possible to have something similar to:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<ClassB> mapping)
{  
   mapping.HasMany(x => x.ClassAIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList()).KeyColumn("Id");
}
```

I don't really understand how to pass a target class type and if it is possible to achieve this at all.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a legacy database?

Comment: Actually this is a _new_ database, but I do not have control over these particular tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are asking.  I think your best bet would be to map it as it appears in the database and handle the loading of that ClassAList collection outside of the mapping.  I would set your automapping up to ignore the collection.  This is just not really a good way to handle relationships from a database perspective.

Comment: Yep, I'm doing this already as it doesn't seem to be any other way around it. Thanks anyway.